# Matching titles, php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My value: ingrid lovesc cops and taxi

I have a mysql table with a field called "title" which has values like:

```
value one: taxi driver bikini
value two: john smith airoplane
value three: taxi driver cops
```

I want a query that sounds something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE myvalue is the closest to a value in "title"
```

Basiclay i want to match my value tu the closest one in the title field.

Comment: seriously, how do u expect to handle: ingrid loves coughs and taxes? word-, letter- or soundex-matching?

Comment: Maybe letters... definetly letters

Comment: "spit and coax" have the same letters as "cops and taxi" and "topic and sax". that's a close match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try add a full-text index into title,
so you can perform full search based on `ingrid lovesc cops and taxi`,
and mysql allow sort by relevancy,
such as http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html`

Comment: Fulltext search is probably the best bet for this.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do the processing in PHP take a look of the functions levenshtein(), metaphone(), similar_text() and soundex() depends the kind of text you are using this functions can help you.

Keep in mind that some of this functions are to be used with english sentences/words so if you are planing to use it in other languaje you may need to find another algorithm.